# Как изменить имя input в многомерном массиве формы при помощи jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть форма:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform" class="myform">
    <div class="person-list">

       <div class="row person-item" id="original-person-item">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group control-wrap">
            <input type="text" name="actorsOther[0][name]" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя на русском" maxlength="200" max="200">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group control-wrap">
            <input type="text" name="actorsOther[0][nameEng]" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя на английском" maxlength="200" max="200">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group control-wrap">
            <input type="text" name="actorsOther[0][nameOrig]" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя на родном" maxlength="200" max="200">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group control-wrap">
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="actorsOther[0][profession][]" data-live-search="true" multiple>
                <option value="1">один</option>
                <option value="2">два</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <button type="button" id="addPerson" class="btn btn-danger">Добавить поле</button>

  <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="submit" onclick="sendform();">Сохранить</button>

</form>

<script>
function sendform(){
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#progress').css('display','block');

  var formData = new FormData(document.forms.myform);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: "../ajax.php?add",
    data:  formData,
    success:function(data){
      $("#messInfo").html(data);
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#progress').css('display','none');
    },
    error:function(data){
      alert('error');
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#progress').css('display','none');
    } 
  })
}
  $('#addPerson').click(function() {
    var newVideoItem = $('#original-person-item').clone();
    newVideoItem.find('.control-wrap').each(function(index) {
    var newSelectpicker = $(this).find(".selectpicker");
      if (newSelectpicker.length) {
        $(this).html(newSelectpicker) 
      newSelectpicker.selectpicker();
      }
    });
    newVideoItem.appendTo(".person-list");
  });
</script>
```

Кнопка добавляет новые поля. Но есть проблема с массивом для получения данных с формы. Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить имена полей формы: [0], [1], [2]... при их добавлении (нажатии на кнопку id="addPerson"). Чтобы при добавлении нового поля было не:

```
actorsOther[0][name]
actorsOther[0][nameEng]
actorsOther[0][nameOrig]
actorsOther[0][profession][]
```

а уже:

```
actorsOther[1][name]
actorsOther[1][nameEng]
actorsOther[1][nameOrig]
actorsOther[1][profession][]

actorsOther[2][name]
actorsOther[2][nameEng]
actorsOther[2][nameOrig]
actorsOther[2][profession][]
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

как-то так ?

```
var count = 0;

$('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
$('#progress').css('display','block');

var formData = new FormData(document.forms.myform);


$('#addPerson').click(function() {
  var newVideoItem = $('#original-person-item').clone();

  count++;
  newVideoItem.find("[name='actorsOther[0][name]']").attr('name', 'actorsOther['+count+'][name]');
  newVideoItem.find("[name='actorsOther[0][nameEng]']").attr('name', 'actorsOther['+count+'][nameEng]');
  newVideoItem.find("[name='actorsOther[0][nameOrig]']").attr('name', 'actorsOther['+count+'][nameOrig]');
  newVideoItem.find("[name='actorsOther[0][profession][]']").attr('name', 'actorsOther['+count+'][profession]');

  newVideoItem.find('.control-wrap').each(function(index) {
  var newSelectpicker = $(this).find(".selectpicker");
    if (newSelectpicker.length) {
      $(this).html(newSelectpicker) 
      //newSelectpicker.selectpicker();
    }
  });
  newVideoItem.appendTo(".person-list");
});
```